# Scheduled alarm never calls receiver class

Tags: android, android-alarms

I'm trying to set an alarm to fire every 5 minutes.

This is the code for setting the alarm :

```
   @Override
public void scheduleAlarmManager() {
    Timber.i("After SignIn sets AlarmManager");
    // broadcast
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PatientAlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(PATIENT_START_ALARM_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);

    // and set alarmManager
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    long currentTIme = currentCal.getTimeInMillis();

    // if there's not an Alarm already set then set one
    if (!isAlarmSet(this)) {
        Timber.i("Alarm not set - so set one");
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                currentTIme + TWO_MINS_DURATION, TWO_MINS_DURATION, pendingIntent);
    }

}
```

and I can verify that I set the alarm correctly since I see in my logcat the messages I log with `Timber`.

My Receiver class is :

```
public class PatientAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String TAG = "PATIENT-ALARM-RECEIVER";
public static final String PATIENT_START_ALARM_ACTION = "bp.headsup.receivers.alarm.patient";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Inside OnReceive Patient");
    Timber.i("Inside OnReceive Patient");

    if (intent == null || intent.getAction() == null) {
        return;
    }

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (PATIENT_START_ALARM_ACTION.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
        onStartCheckForConnectionRequest(context);
    }
}

/**
 * If is connected to network starts services
 */
private void onStartCheckForConnectionRequest(Context context) {
    NetworkUtils networkUtils = new NetworkUtils(context);
    if (networkUtils.isNetworkConnected()) {
        Intent checkForConnRequestIntent = new Intent(context, PatientCheckForConnectionRequestService.class);
        context.startService(checkForConnRequestIntent);
        Timber.i("Starts Service From PatientALARMMANAGER");
    }
}
```

}

And I have declared in Manifest :

```
        <!-- Receivers -->
    <receiver
        android:name="bp.headsup.receivers.PatientAlarmReceiver" />
```

Also if I run : `adb shell dumpsys alarm`
I can see  :

```
  ELAPSED_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{42d804e8 type 2 bp.headsup.mock}
operation=PendingIntent{42d0c230: PendingIntentRecord{42d0f000 bp.headsup.mock broadcastIntent}}
```

Mock in the above response is the sourceSet I'm using - dont know if it has anything to do with this I just mention it.

The problem is I never read in logcat the messages I have in `onReceive` on my Receiver class, and obviously no service starts. Anyone can help with that ? I'm using a device which runs with kitKat 4.4 (api 19) but I have tried it with an emulator too and the result was the same.

Comment: I think you have not set action(BOOT_COMPLETED) of receiver in menifest.

Comment: You're setting an elapsed time alarm, but you're giving it a "wall clock" starting time. Either change the alarm to an `RTC` type, or get your starting time from `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`.

Comment: @MikeM.  Correct! it worked! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting an `ELAPSED_REALTIME` alarm, which is based on the time since the last boot. However, you're passing it a starting time based on the "wall clock", so your alarm is actually set quite far in the future.

You can either change the alarm to an `RTC` type, or get the starting time from `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`. Given your described behavior, keeping the elapsed type and correcting the starting time seems appropriate.